# How to add Letterbox to the Video I have shot?

Tags: video-editor, editing

I would like to add letterbox to the 1080p video I have shot. How can I add it?

Which software should I use? I have Premiere Pro and After Effects.
What technique should I use?

Comment: What format are you trying to move to?  Do you have a particular resolution it needs to fit?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  This will impact the best way to scale the video.

Comment: My videos are of 1920x1080 resolution & I would like to add letterboxing to the videos of that resolution. @AJ Henderson♦

Comment: So you are specifically looking to crop them so they won't go full screen?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. Can you post an answer for that? @AJ Henderson♦

Comment: do you want the resolution of the video altered so that it will only take up that space or do you actually still want a 1080p video with black boxes (note, this will waste bits in the video file).  If you can give some more detail about the context you are using it in and why you need it cropped in this manner, then we may be able to provide better advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to add letterboxing in PP.

Some ways I have done are:

1. creating a Photoshop file (or finding one already made) and using an adjustment layer to apply it. ( I used this post http://whoismatt.com/cinemascopetutorial/)
2. when exporting you can use the crop function to chop the top and bottom off
3. using an adjustment layer again but cropping it in 132 from top and 132 from bottom ( believe)
4. make a new Sequence, using Custom settings that's 1920 x 816.
5. google has loads of sites if you do a quick search letterboxing in adobe premier

I hope some of the above help in a way